# Flex: X-out Label?

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to make a label that has an X over it. Like so I can say was this price with an X over the price. I want to make it a component because I am going to use it more than once. I want the X to be close to the same size as the text so that it is not a giant X over small text or a small X over large text.

Here is the code I tried which did nothing at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Label xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            override public function set text(value:String):void
            {
                super.text = value;

                var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
                g.clear();
                g.lineStyle(3,0xFF0000);
                g.lineTo(this.width,this.height);
                g.moveTo(0,this.height);
                g.lineTo(this.width,0);
            }       

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.cubicleman.com/2007/05/10/strike-through-text-component/) post. It provides a component which will do this for you.

It's not currently supported natively.